# Hamburger menu (Between lines are unclickable)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position, pseudo-element

I have encountered a problem where I tried to click between black lines and it doesn't triggered anything, but triggers when clicked on the black lines.  I added div so that I can add cursor pointer around the area.  I am aware that it must be something with the for=nav-trigger located in the html, however "for" doesn't work with div.  Is there a workaround?

```
<div id="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger"/>
  <label id="menuButton" for="nav-trigger"></label>
</div>
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dxs6040/51wdfypj/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the html like this:

```
<div id="menu">
  <label for="nav-trigger">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
    <span id="menuButton"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

and add this to css:

```
label {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/e9qafkbr/